# How do you stop settlers from being hostile in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

There was one of those two headed cows walking around sancutary. When I shot it, my entire settlement went hostile and tried to kill me. Sadly, I dont have any saves before this. Anyone know how to get them friendly again or am I just screwed and cant go back to sanctuary?

Comment: corpses aren't hostile. muahahahaha

Comment: Please include your platform, as no-doubt there are console commands on PC for this, but answers will differ for consoles.

Comment: This hasn't happened to me, but I've read that if you don't shoot any of them, you should be able to leave the area for two or three game days and return to find it pacified.

Comment: If you try what @CPerkins suggested, probably shouldn't return with a weapon out..

Comment: The two-headed cows (brahmin) arrive at your settlement once you have a high-ish Food production, and apparently the settlers consider  them part of the family. To stop them wandering around getting in the way build a "Brahmin Feed Trough" and put it out of the way somewhere, they will stay near that.

Comment: Fallout 4 doesn't have *yield* like Skyrim?

Comment: Note that if you have the power armor tesla mod, the mod will attack hostiles, making it impossible to yield by putting your weapon away.

Comment: @Mazura: unfortunately, no. I expected them to have it but nopes. I believe settlers spawn so often with radio towers that you can just kill them off.

Comment: "Yielding is an action possible [!] in Fallout 3, Fallout: New Vegas, and Fallout 4 where if the player is to initiate combat with a friendly NPC, either accidentally or on purpose, they can **un-initiate combat by holstering their weapon within the first 10 seconds of combat.** "https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Yielding

Answer (score 8):

I had something similar happen in Tenpines Bluff - there was a raider attack, and one of the settlers ran into the path of my VATS shot and turned hostile. Unfortunately, Codsworth was with me and so even putting away my gun didn't stop him from continuing to attack the settler, so I couldn't get them to un-hostile-ify. I tried running far away from the settlement and ordering Codsworth to wait, then returning, but by then the settler was too angry to calm down.

To solve the problem, I ran away again, dismissed Codsworth (instructing him to reside in Sanctuary), then fast-traveled to Sanctuary myself. I slept for 24 hours and fast-traveled back to Tenpines Bluff, and the settler was no longer hostile.

If Sanctuary is your only settlement so far, then just head back over to Vault 111 and sleep in the Overseer's bed, and the settlers in Sanctuary should calm down. Or find a bed in Concord, that should work too.

Comment: In Fallout 4, sleeping for 24 hours can reset some hostilities.

Answer (score 1):

If they attack maybe you should try putting your weapon away. They may forgive you and stop attacking.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/172605)

Comment: @DangerZone i think is a valid answer, maybe after edit?

Answer (score 0):

Wait 5 days worked for me I slept in someone's bed I waited/slept for 5 days then boom nobody attacked

Comment: Oh and if you kill main characters they come back so don't try killing them.