# How can I explode the truck in front of Diamond City entrance without turning people hostile?

Tags: fallout-4

I set myself a goal long ago when I started playing Fallout 4 vanilla that I would explode every vehicle and every explosive item on the map.

I have blown up canisters of gas.  I have blown up the small blue and red zip cars.  I have blown up pickups, vans, convertibles, big and small.  I have blown up trucks.  I have blown up things under water.  I have blown up unreachable vehicles on top of roads that you cant go to.

But what irks me the most is the truck in front of Diamond city.  I can't seem to find a way to blow it up without making the entire area hostile. I have timed it that every guard is away from the area and blown it up but still causing everyone to turn hostile.

Is there a way to blow it up without turning everyone hostile in that area?

Comment: What about using a long range silenced weapon to try and blow it up from afar? If they can't see you, and can't tell where the shot is coming from, they won't be able to go hostile towards you I would think.  I use to use a 10mm silenced pistol that had explosive rounds that would make quick work of vehicles. The pistol wouldn't be good at range, but I think if I tried hard enough, I could get some shots to land from a distance.

Comment: You know blown up vehicles respawn right?

Comment: [How do you stop settlers from being hostile in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/251453/how-do-you-stop-settlers-from-being-hostile-in-fallout-4). You can try yielding (put your gun away in the first ten seconds) or wait for one day to upwards of a week. You could try setting ownership of the car in the console to yourself.  You could try spawning a suicider right by it and blame them ;) You could 'mark it for delete' if it's really bothering you....

Comment: @Nelson that is why i like blowing stuff up.

Answer (score 5):

You can try calling a Vertibird nearby.

NPC characters have a much shorter spawn range than vehicles.  A Vertibird will let you get the range you need and blow up the truck without any NPCs nearby.

Of course, save the game before trying, but I've shot up vehicles near known NPC locations and have never accidentally killed anyone.

Comment: I will try this later or tomorrow.  Since I am currently hostile with the BOS and have not yet done the quest for the railroad to get a vertibird.

Comment: tried this. killed two guards.  maybe i should just use the console and stop AI when everyone is away then blow up the truck and start AI again.

Comment: That's odd.  Did you go far enough just before the cars despawn?  The cars spawn VERY far away.

Comment: I think the guards just spawn near the truck and walk past it all the time.  I don't want to kill non aggro NPC's.  I have done that with the BOS and shot them from the top of a building and it did not go aggro.  I think they just walk past the truck too often to make this work.